# can we use system.web.mail in wcf?

Tags: wcf, system.web.mail

can we use system.web.mail in wcf library if yes then how can i get system.web.mail.dll

Answer (score 0):

These classes have been deprecated, you should use System.Net.Mail instead.

But yes, you can use them from WCF.